# Why might DeviceCapabilities() return 4294967295 for DC_BINS?

Tags: winapi, printing

I'm fetching the selected printer tray from a WIN32 call to `PrintDlgEx()`. This seems to work successfully *most* of the time, but recently I added a new printer to my machine (a DYMO LabelWriter 450) and it caused my simple software to fail.

Upon investigation, the call to `DeviceCapabilities()` for `DC_BINS` is returning 4294967295, while all of the other printers I've tested so far return single digit bin counts.

My first inclination is to omit the bin name when the bin count is greater than a given threshold (say... 20?), but I don't *love* this solution.

Is there a known reason that a printer would return the max `UNSIGNED INT` value for this? Is it just poorly written drivers, or is there an alternate meaning? Or perhaps I totally misunderstand the intended value.

If I have to write an arbitrary cap I will, but I'd like to better understand why this situation exists. Clearly, this printer doesn't have billions of different printer trays.

Here's an MRE:

```cpp
    HINSTANCE hinst = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    HRESULT hResult;
    PRINTDLGEX pdx = {0};
    LPPRINTPAGERANGE pPageRanges = NULL;
    HWND hWndOwner = GetForegroundWindow();

    if(!hWndOwner){
        hWndOwner = GetDesktopWindow();
    }

    // Allocate an array of PRINTPAGERANGE structures.
    pPageRanges = (LPPRINTPAGERANGE) GlobalAlloc(GPTR, 10 * sizeof(PRINTPAGERANGE));
    if(!pPageRanges){
        return wprintf(L"{\"error\": \"%s\"}", GetLastError()); // "Your computer does not have enough memory to complete this operation:"
    }

    //  Initialize the PRINTDLGEX structure.
    pdx.lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLGEX);
    pdx.hwndOwner = hWndOwner;
    pdx.hDevMode = NULL;
    pdx.hDevNames = NULL;
    pdx.hDC = NULL;
    pdx.Flags = PD_RETURNDC | PD_COLLATE;
    pdx.Flags2 = 0;
    pdx.ExclusionFlags = 0;
    pdx.nPageRanges = 0;
    pdx.nMaxPageRanges = 10;
    pdx.lpPageRanges = pPageRanges;
    pdx.nMinPage = 1;
    pdx.nMaxPage = 1000;
    pdx.nCopies = 1;
    pdx.hInstance = 0;
    pdx.lpPrintTemplateName = NULL;
    pdx.lpCallback = NULL;
    pdx.nPropertyPages = 0;
    pdx.lphPropertyPages = NULL;
    pdx.nStartPage = START_PAGE_GENERAL;
    pdx.dwResultAction = 0;

    //  Invoke the Print property sheet.
    hResult = PrintDlgEx(&pdx);

    DEVMODE * myDevMode     = (DEVMODE *)GlobalLock(pdx.hDevMode);
    DWORD binCount = DeviceCapabilities((CHAR*)myDevMode->dmDeviceName, nullptr, DC_BINS, nullptr, nullptr);
    DWORD binNameCount = DeviceCapabilities((CHAR*)myDevMode->dmDeviceName, nullptr, DC_BINNAMES, nullptr, nullptr);
    wprintf(L"\"binCount\":\"%lu\",", binCount);
    wprintf(L"\"binNameCount\":\"%lu\",", binNameCount);
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's pretty difficult to answer questions about why something isn't working properly. You should post a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. Chances are good that you're just failing to initialize something before calling `DeviceCapabilities`. And as paper bins are physical paper trays, even large printers seldom have more than four or five.

Comment: @KenWhite - Thanks. Please note that I'm not asking why the code does not function, but under what circumstance a printer driver would return 4294967295 as the number of paper trays. Perhaps the code *is* the reason, but I don't believe so.

Comment: You're typing too much. :-) If you use `ZeroMemory` to zero out the entire structure and then just populate the ones you're using, you can reduce that 21 lines of code (the ones that initialize `pdx`) to 10. It also ensures you don't miss anything. I don't see any obvious issues in your code, though  (other than it's not a [mre], because it's incomplete).

Comment: @Kenwhite - *and* my code totally was at fault. Taking my foot out of my mouth now :)

Comment: Yeah, I see Remy caught something I didn't, any more than you did. :-) Glad you got it sorted out. My suggestion about `ZeroMemory` still applies, though.

Comment: I don't typically work with C++ or Win32, so this code is incredibly foreign to me. I *really* appreciate both of you!

Comment: @KenWhite "*If you use `ZeroMemory` to zero out the entire structure ...*" - that is exactly what the `= {0}` in `PRINTDLGEX pdx = {0};` is already doing.

Comment: @Remy: I didn't notice it. I just noticed all the `NULL` values in the 21 lines of initialization code, which can be omitted completely if the memory has been cleared already.

Comment: @KenWhite - Only the NULLs, or can I safely omit the zeros as well?

Comment: @AaronCicali: Both. You just have to leave the lines that you actually need for your purpose. Anything that is `NULL` or `0` can be removed. Remy's code shows you what is needed, which is considerably less than what you had originally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DeviceCapabilities()` returns a *signed* `int`, not an *unsigned* `DWORD`.

The unsigned value `4294967295` is hex `0xFFFFFFFF`, which is the same numeric value as a signed `-1`.

Per the `DeviceCapabilities()` documentation:

> Return value
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value depends on the setting of the fwCapability parameter. A return value of zero generally indicates that, while the function completed successfully, there was some type of failure, such as a capability that is not supported. For more details, see the descriptions for the fwCapability values.
>
> **If the function returns -1, this may mean either that the capability is not supported or there was a general function failure.**

You are not accounting for the possibility of `DeviceCapabilities()` failing (or `PrintDlgEx()`, either).

Try this:

```cpp
HWND hWndOwner = GetForegroundWindow();
if (!hWndOwner){
    hWndOwner = GetDesktopWindow();
}

// Allocate an array of PRINTPAGERANGE structures.
LPPRINTPAGERANGE pPageRanges = (LPPRINTPAGERANGE) GlobalAlloc(GPTR, 10 * sizeof(PRINTPAGERANGE));
if (!pPageRanges){
    // NOTE: GetLastError() returns DWORD, not TCHAR*! So, if you
    // want to translate the error code in a human-readable string,
    // use FormatMessage() instead...
    return wprintf(L"{\"error\": %lu}", GetLastError());
}

//  Initialize the PRINTDLGEX structure.
PRINTDLGEX pdx = {0};
pdx.lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLGEX);
pdx.hwndOwner = hWndOwner;
pdx.Flags = PD_RETURNDC | PD_COLLATE;
pdx.nMaxPageRanges = 10;
pdx.lpPageRanges = pPageRanges;
pdx.nMinPage = 1;
pdx.nMaxPage = 1000;
pdx.nCopies = 1;
pdx.nStartPage = START_PAGE_GENERAL;

HRESULT hResult = PrintDlgEx(&pdx);
if (hResult != S_OK)
{
    GlobalFree(reinterpret_cast<HGLOBAL>(pPageRanges));
    return wprintf(L"{\"error\": %d}", hResult);
}

if (pdx.dwResultAction == PD_RESULT_CANCEL)
{
    GlobalFree(reinterpret_cast<HGLOBAL>(pPageRanges));
    return wprintf(L"{\"error\": \"cancelled\"}");
}

DEVMODE *myDevMode = (DEVMODE*) GlobalLock(pdx.hDevMode);

int binCount = DeviceCapabilities(reinterpret_cast<TCHAR*>(myDevMode->dmDeviceName), nullptr, DC_BINS, nullptr, nullptr);
wprintf(L"\"binCount\":%d,", binCount);

int binNameCount = DeviceCapabilities(reinterpret_cast<TCHAR*>(myDevMode->dmDeviceName), 
nullptr, DC_BINNAMES, nullptr, nullptr);
wprintf(L"\"binNameCount\":%d,", binNameCount);

if (binCount == -1)
{
    ...
}

if (binNameCount == -1)
{
    ...
}

...

GlobalUnlock(pdx.hDevMode);
GlobalFree(reinterpret_cast<HGLOBAL>(pPageRanges));

return ...;
```